# Unable to find MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

**Background:**

I have been given a project that other people were on previously. I'm still trying to put pieces together as there was no documentation on anything. Basically I am unable to find the MongoDB.

This is a NodeJS/MeteorJS web application that has a Digital Ocean droplet and an AWS S3 (for profile pictures).

I was assumming the MongoDb would be where the app is hosted (on the droplet) but this has not been the case.

**What I have Tried:**

I tried logging into the Digital Ocean console and running `mongo` but it seems that mongo isn't even installed. That seems to me that the database isn't there.

I looked around a bit on the server and found a `mongodb.conf` file in `opt/mongodb`. All that is inside is the default it seems: `dbpath=/data/dbroot`

I have also tried looking through the code to maybe find some clues or something but have had no luck.

**Question:**

How can I find where this database is? Is it possible without having to contact the people who were on the project before me?

Thanks.

Comment: Mostly for production environments database is on another separate instance. You have to ask the previously involved people if that's the case.

Comment: Check digital ocean conf params of the app, you may find the mongo URL setting

Comment: @Yann Where can I find that at?

Comment: Connect to the digital ocean console and check in the /etc/init folder for .conf file that may match your app name. If it's the case, you should find the MONGO_URL param in it

Comment: @Yann There doesn't seem to be a .conf filed that matches my app name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application utilizes mupx and not mup.

To access the database, login into the server and run:

`docker exec -it mongodb mongo <appName>`

The above command will put you into the mongoDB shell.

You can then use `show dbs`, `use dbName` and `show collections` to see the data in the database.

**Reference:**

https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#accessing-the-database

Answer (score 2):

If you have a node project on you server than you should have access to the code. You should look for the line where the connection to mongodb is initialised.  It could either be hardcoded or an environment variable.

For example, something like this:

```
// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  db.close();
});
```

What I want to say is that if you have access to the project you don't need to contact the team before you.

As you are using Meteor, there should be a `settings.json` file setting the `MONGO_URL` variable. There you'd find the address of your database. If there isn't they might be setting it as an environent variable and you can simply echo MONGO_URL:

```
echo $MONGO_URL
```

But the possibilities are many. You should read the code if this doesn't work and look for the value (you can even log it from inside the project)

Comment: settings.json is empty. How do I use the echo $MONGO_URL?

Comment: On the shell machine shell

Comment: It only seems to return a blank line.

Comment: The you must look inside the project's code ther should be the string hardcoded or the environemnt variable being used

Comment: There is quite a bit of code. Do you know where I should start?

Comment: look for the word mongo on all files

Comment: should be on some configuration or initialisation, but it's difficult to guess without knowing the project

Comment: I've searched the contents of the files up and down and the only MONGO_URL there is, is the one in my mup.js. But, I obviously need the MONGO_URL to fill that out. Which is my main problem.

Comment: Found this `var mongoUrl = process.env.MONGO_URL;`

Not sure how to trace that though.

Comment: That is assuming you have an environment variable called MONGO_URL - it is probably set in the NGINX vhost file

Comment: @Mikkel Where can I find that file?

Comment: The installation is likely to be using nginx (but might be using apache), the config files can usually be found in /etc/nginx/sites-eanbled/

Comment: @Mikkel /etc/ doesn't seem to have nginx.

Comment: @Mikkel When I use find on 'nginx' I get something saying invalid user nginx from 123.123.123.123 (real ip address though). I get a bunch of those for various dates.

grep -ri 'mongo_url' doesn't seem to return anything either.

Comment: I think it should be grep -Ri. If /etc/nginx doesn't exist, then it's not using nginx. Or you can check the process list ps -ef | grep nginx

Comment: @Mikkel that outputs this: `root      9963  9933  0 00:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx`

Comment: basically that means nginx isn't running, because all you found in the process list was your own grep command. so it must be running using something else like forever or apache (httpd)

Comment: I think it'd be easier to just edit the code and add a `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);` then you don't even need to know where the value is stored

Comment: @andresk Seems I just get `undefined`

Seemed like a solid approach though. This is only on my local, I don't know how I could do that on a live version of the app to get the actual location?